# htaccess code for redirecting sub folder to the root domain without affecting other sub domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

The issue is in my `public_html` directory I have a www7 folder, which I used as a root domain link. Like if anyone visit `example.com` or `www.example.com` it redirects it to `www7.example.com`.
For this I have used this below htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www7\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I also have many other sub domains under `public_html` like, `sub1.exaple.com` , `sub2.exaple.com`.
Now I want that tough my main files are present in `www7` folder, whenever anyone open `exaple.com` it will actually openup the files inside `www7` folder, but have to make sure that the other sub domains under public html should not get affected.
Also in the `www7` folder a wordpress site has been hosted, so it needs to be wordpress friendly too. Also if anybody open `www.exaple.com` it will redirect him to `exaple.com`. I think for this, the below code will work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mynewwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But not sure about the directory issue. Please help.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly is the problem. Can you clarify with some examples.

Comment: There is no problem mate. See if you visit my site http://isaumya.com, it will redirect you to www8.isaumya.com because the site is present in ww8 directory under public_html. But I'm asking is there any way to run my site as http://isaumya.com while the files remains in www8 directory. I hope now you understand it.

Comment: Yes I understand it now. can you post your existing .htaccess

Comment: I posted it in the above question. the 1st htaccess code.

Comment: Is that all of the code? Also is there any htaccess in www8?

Comment: This is htaccess within www8 : http://pastebin.com/fMmrN7Ei

Comment: And this the whole htaccess of the root directory: http://pastebin.com/s59Q4sbq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^isaumya\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.isaumya\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www8\.isaumya\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Replace this rule with:

```
RewriteRule !^www8/ /www8%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, did you looked into the other post I mailed you? I'm really worried about that. Can you please take a look?